# How show my own data in list (verticaly) wxWidgets

Tags: list, listview, wxwidgets

I have my own data in list. List is specyfic, and data are binary and text.

How display|show each of record my data in wxWidgets 
I need only simple list similar wxListCtrl. Meybe Virtual List, Dataview?

My data for example:

```
[integer,string[5],short]
[integer,string[5],short]
 .....
```

I need list of

"number text"

"number text"

etc....

Comment: It's really not clear what are you asking here. Is the question about what control is better to use? Or about how to do what you want to do with some particular control? More generally, what have you tried to do and what didn't work, exactly?

Comment: what control is better to use and how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just a single column, use `wxListBox`. If you need multiple columns but no hierarchical data, use `wxListCtrl` (or rather `wxListView` as you will only be using it in report mode). If there are a lot of items (more than a couple of thousands) or if it is just more convenient because you already have the data elsewhere, make it virtual. If you need hierarchy too, use `wxDataViewCtrl`.

Of course, all of the above are just the minimal requirements, so you could also use `wxDataViewCtrl` even if you need just a single column.

Comment: I have single column, but I have my own data, wxListCtrl have strings as data

Comment: Then you should use virtual `wxListView` and override its `OnGetItemText()` to return the textual representation of your data.